# Where does the chat get the thumbnail on Wikipedia links from?

Tags: support, chat, images, wikipedia

Starting [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/846211#846211), we kind of wondered *how* the chat selects the preview picture. But with [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/846280#846280), we changed our direction: *where* does the chat get these pictures from? The displayed pyramids picture is nowhere to be seen on the page itself (unless I overlooked something)!

Comment: The image is listed as "in use" by the Isis article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:All_Gizah_Pyramids.jpg I can't see where, though, not even in older versions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>It just picks the largest (to be precise, tallest) image on the page as returned by Wikipedia's API – and that particular image, even if only displayed as a tiny thumbnail, has a [height of 2906](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:All_Gizah_Pyramids.jpg) pixels.</s>

In most cases, the largest image is a good representation of the Wikipedia article (I tested a lot); in this case, it's so-so. I've seen worse, though: The image for the [Wolfgang Petry article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Petry) is a picture of Johann Sebastian Bach – but you probably have to be German to “appreciate” that :)

We're now using Wikipedia's [PageImages API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPageImages); see my updated answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103252/115866).

Comment: So it inspects the image quite a bit, eh? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if multiple images have the same, tallest height?

Answer (score 5):

There is hidden (`display:none`) picture for that in the Wikipedia page source:

```
<tr>
    <td class="navbox-abovebelow"
        style="background-color:#decd87;"
        colspan="3">
        <a href="/wiki/File:All_Gizah_Pyramids.jpg" class="image">
        <img alt="All Gizah Pyramids.jpg"
             src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/All_Gizah_Pyramids.jpg/30px-All_Gizah_Pyramids.jpg"
             width="30"
             height="20" />
        </a>
        <a href="/wiki/Portal:Ancient_Egypt"
           title="Portal:Ancient Egypt">
        <b>Ancient Egypt Portal</b></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you click show on the right corner of that block, you would see that picture :D

[image]

Comment: Was just about to post this. I don't understand what the meaning of this is, though - the image has no `rel` attribute, no nothing... Doesn't look clean to me

Comment: We found out that it is unhidden by clicking `[show]` on the bar at the bottom of the page, reading "Ancient Egyptian religion". It is a really tiny image at the bottom of the expanded area.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be extracting the image from the last [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) `<a>` tag with the attribute `image="class"` on the article.