# The Wikipedia thumbnail should be taken from the infobox div over the largest image

Tags: feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wikipedia Chat One-Boxing doesn't always pick the correct image from the article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103244/wikipedia-chat-one-boxing-doesnt-always-pick-the-correct-image-from-the-article)

According to [this meta-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94818/where-does-the-chat-get-the-thumbnail-on-wikipedia-links-from), the thumbnail image chosen for Wikipedia previews posted in chat is the largest image on the page.

Wouldn't it make more sense to grab the image contained within the infobox div, and if no such image exists, *then* grab the largest image on the page? Ideally, the image contained in the infobox should be more relevant then the largest image on the page.

Take the engineer article for example. Currently it grabs this image:

[image]

However, I believe it should grab this image instead, contained in the infobox div:

[image]

Comment: You were just beaten out by Nick T: [Wikipedia Chat One-Boxing picks images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103244/wikipedia-chat-one-boxing-picks-images) You two probably want to combine forces.

Comment: NickT is still suggesting to choose the largest image on the page.

Comment: I can agree with your edit though.